# Sub-process in Python execute two task?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, terminal, subprocess

I am facing some python coding issue, which I can't solve yet. I am trying to write a python script, which should perform two tasks: open a new xterm terminal and then execute nmap in xterm with some nmap argument.
First task is not difficult just use simple program:

```
import os
subprocess.call(['xterm &'],shell=True)
```

but second task, I don't have any idea how to write it. Can you guys help me to write this script.

Comment: What does the second task do? Can't you just `subprocess.call()` it, too?

Comment: to run nmap script in execute terminal xterm....

Comment: You can use the `-e` argument of `xterm` to put your 2nd command on the same line as your `xterm` call.  http://linux.die.net/man/1/xterm "-e program [ arguments ... ]
This option specifies the program (and its command line arguments) to be run in the xterm window."

Comment: no it not work...let me clear what i am try do,,,in subprocess open xterm and in a xterm execute nmap with his argument and in python script...i hope it's clear if not plz replay....and you have solution plz write script

Comment: unrelated: you don't need the shell here, use `Popen()` instead `call()`: `subprocess.Popen(['xterm', '-e', 'sudo nmap -v -sS -O 10.2.2.2'])`

Comment: hey sebastian thanks bro for solve my problem your solution is work. but there execute xterm and nmap xterm are close immediately  ,,,,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(['xterm', '-hold', '-e', 'nmap -sV 74.125.130.100'])
```

this is more easy to execute

Answer (score 2):

To run `nmap` in a new `xterm` window, you could use `-e` option:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen(['xterm', '-e', 'bash -c "sudo nmap -v -sS -O 10.2.2.2; read"'])
```

`read` is appended to wait for <kbd>Enter</kbd> after `nmap` exits before closing the window.

Comment: thanks J.F. Sebastian...for replay. i have solve my problem...and thanks again.